# Sorting array of pointers to Node using C qsort

Tags: c, arrays, qsort

I have a Node

```
struct Node{
  int age;
  int level;
  Node( int a , int l ):age(a),level(l){};
}
```

array of pointers to node

```
   Node **arr = new Node*[n]
```

and i want to sort this array using c qsort.

i defined compare function

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
return ( ( ( Node * )a )->level - ( ( Node * )b )->level );

}
```

and invoked qsort

```
 qsort( arr, ( size_t )n, sizeof( Node* ), compare );
```

and yet the array isnt sorted, its been a while since a used C ( even in c++ ) . Why am i doing wrong?

Comment: The dup also uses the correct way of comparing the values - not risking integer overflow as you do. Your way might be OK if the values are small, but not a good habit to get into.

Comment: `Node( int a , int l ):age(a),level(l){}` That does not look like valid C. Neither does the rest.